# How to transform array into textfile?

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-7

I am currently creating a windows phone 7 application. How do I transform all the values of an array to textfile so I can print out all the values stored in that particular array inside another page listbox, and then store inside an isolated storage. 
Thanks! :(

I tried this method but it doesn't work.
**For ViewList.xaml.cs**

```
    private void addListBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Obtain the virtual store for application
        IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        //Create a new folder and call it "ImageFolder"
        myStore.CreateDirectory("ListFolder");


        //Create a new file and assign a StreamWriter to the store and this new file (myFile.txt)
        //Also take the text contents from the txtWrite control and write it to myFile.txt

        StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ListFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myStore));
        writeFile.WriteLine(retrieveDrinksListBox);
        writeFile.Close();
     }
```

**FavouriteList.xaml.cs**

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        //Obtain a virtual store for application
        IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        //This code will open and read the contents of retrieveDrinksListBox
        //Add exception in case the user attempts to click “Read button first.

        StreamReader readFile = null;

        try
        {
            readFile = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ListFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore));
            string fileText = readFile.ReadLine();

            if (fileText != "")
            {

                listNumberListBox.Items.Add("List 1");
            }

            //The control txtRead will display the text entered in the file
            listNumberListBox.Items.Add(fileText);
            readFile.Close();

        }

        catch
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Need to create directory and the file first.");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write away the serialized items/data of the listbox, not the listbox itself.

When reading them again, you must deserialize them.The [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) example on MSDN has code samples showing you how to write away an object to a (file)stream and how to recover the object again from that same stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display contents of your file (say, lines) in listbox, read entire file content at once and [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) the lines:

```
string fileText = readFile.ReadToEnd();
string[] lines = fileText.Split(Enviroment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), 
                                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
listNumberListBox.Items.AddRange(lines);
```

Other way around is similar, fetch items from your listbox, by [joining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) them with new line, and dump at once to file:

```
string fileContents = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                                  retrieveDrinksListBox.Items.Cast<string>());
writeFile.WriteLine(fileContents);
```