# Transform array into text file and store in isolated storage

Tags: arrays, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to transform all the data inside my array into textfile, so as to read all the item one by one and save it into an isolated storage and displaying it out in another page listbox.

I tried this but i encounter error stating "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream". I need help in this, and please get back to me asap. Thank you!

```
    //save list to favourite list
    private void addListBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ///////for-loop to access userDrinksList
        //////transform array into textfile, one line for each drink
        ///////write in quantity of file into isolated storage using write line function

        for (int i = 0; i < (Application.Current as App).userDrinksList.Count; i++)
        {

            //Obtain the virtual store for application
            IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            //Create a new folder and call it "ListFolder"
            storage.CreateDirectory("ListFolder");


            //Create a new file and assign a StreamWriter to the store and this new file (myFile.txt)
            //Also take the text contents from the txtWrite control and write it to myFile.txt
           // StreamReader readFile = null;
            StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ListFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, storage));
            StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ListFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, storage));

            string myFile = readFile.ReadToEnd();
            string[] lines = myFile.Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            //write content inside myFile.txt
            writeFile.WriteLine(myFile); 

            //retrieveDrinksListBox.Items.AddRange(lines); 
            //writeFile.Close();
        }
```

Comment: how is this different to your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740729/how-to-transform-array-into-textfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you're seeing is thrown when you attempt to read from the file you just opened for writing:

`StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ListFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, storage`));

The problem is also that you never close the file when you've read it (Although you haven't gotten far enough in the code to have an issue with that). All the code you have is good, you just need to reorder it. Try

```
StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ListFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, storage));

            string myFile = readFile.ReadToEnd();
            readFile.Close();

            //Create a new file and assign a StreamWriter to the store and this new file (myFile.txt)
            //Also take the text contents from the txtWrite control and write it to myFile.txt
            // StreamReader readFile = null;
            StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ListFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, storage));

            string[] lines = myFile.Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            //write content inside myFile.txt
            writeFile.WriteLine(myFile);

            //retrieveDrinksListBox.Items.AddRange(lines); 
            writeFile.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a little more information on the exception being thrown? By reading your code it looks like you are trying to append to the file. You can eliminate the `StreamReader` by simply setting the `FileMode` to `Append` during the creation of the `StreamWriter`. See below:

```
StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(
    new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ListFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Append, storage));
```

`FileMode.Append` will either append to the file if it exists, or create a new file.

Also, I'm not sure if you intended the line `writeFile.WriteLine(myFile)` to write `myFile` rather than the what is stored in the `lines` variable (your data).

Comment: No, I am not trying to append to the file. 

Instead, I would want to create a for-loop to access data stored inside my array and transform data inside that array to text file. So that I can use `string myFile = readFile.ReadToEnd();` method to read through all the data stored inside the array, and save it in an isolated storage. After that, I can retrieve the data out line by line in a listbox of another page.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to use a for-loop to access data inside my array, create an isolated storage to store all the data inside(transform array data to text file) and use `StreamReader` to read all the text file data line by line. I have to save the text file which is being read inside the isolated storage file again, so as to retrieve it at another page.